How to write $\displaystyle \sum\limits_{\text{cyc}}(a-b)(a-c)(a-d)(a-e)$ as the sum of squares?

How to write $\displaystyle \sum\limits_{\text{cyc}}(a-b)(a-c)(a-d)(a-e)$ as a sum of squares?

This problem comes from 1971 IMO problem 1,which is stated as follows. Prove that the following assertion is true for $n=3$ and $n=5$, and that it is false for every other natural number $n>2$: If $a_1,\cdots,a_n$ are arbitrary reals, then $$\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\prod\limits_{j\neq i}(a_i-a_j)\geq 0.$$
Now we only care about the case when $n=5$, and the proof is given below.
Proof Let $a_1\leq\cdots\leq a_n$. First we have $$\sum\limits_{i=1}^5\prod\limits_{j\neq i}(a_i-a_j)=(a_1-a_2)\bigg((a_1-a_3)(a_1-a_4)(a_1-a_5)-(a_2-a_3)(a_2-a_4)(a_2-a_5)\bigg)+\prod\limits_{j\neq 3}(a_3-a_j)+(a_5-a_4)\bigg((a_5-a_3)(a_5-a_2)(a_5-a_1)-(a_4-a_3)(a_4-a_2)(a_4-a_1)\bigg).$$ Second, it's easy to verify that $a_1-a_3\leq a_2-a_3\leq 0$, $a_1-a_4\leq a_2-a_4\leq 0$, $a_1-a_5\leq a_2-a_5\leq 0$, $a_5-a_3\geq a_4-a_3\geq 0$, $a_5-a_2\geq a_4-a_2\geq 0$, $a_5-a_1\geq a_4-a_1\geq 0$, which implies $$(a_1-a_3)(a_1-a_4)(a_1-a_5)\leq (a_2-a_3)(a_2-a_4)(a_2-a_5)\\(a_5-a_3)(a_5-a_2)(a_5-a_1)\geq (a_4-a_3)(a_4-a_2)(a_4-a_1).$$ Then we have $$(a_1-a_2)\bigg((a_1-a_3)(a_1-a_4)(a_1-a_5)-(a_2-a_3)(a_2-a_4)(a_2-a_5)\bigg)\geq 0\\(a_5-a_4)\bigg((a_5-a_3)(a_5-a_2)(a_5-a_1)-(a_4-a_3)(a_4-a_2)(a_4-a_1)\bigg)\geq 0.$$ Third, $\displaystyle \prod\limits_{j\neq 3}(a_3-a_j)\geq 0$, and therefore all the above three terms are non-negative, which implies $\displaystyle \sum\limits_{i=1}^5\prod\limits_{j\neq i}(a_i-a_j)\geq 0.$
From the above discussions, we know that $\displaystyle \sum\limits_{\text{cyc}}(a-b)(a-c)(a-d)(a-e)$ is non-negative. Therefore, I'm attempting to write it as the sum of squares, and the first thing comes to my mind is Hilbert's seventeenth problem. In this link, it's claimed that when a homogeneous polynomial of degree $2d\;(2d\geq 4)$ and $n\;(n\geq 4)$ variables can not necessarily be represented as sum of squares. In this problem $2d=4$ and $n=5$, so I'm not sure $\displaystyle \sum\limits_{\text{cyc}}(a-b)(a-c)(a-d)(a-e)$ can be written as a sum of squares. Please help if you have any idea for proving or disproving this problem.
By the way, there's a simple proof for the statement that for an arbitrary single-variable polynomial of even degrees which only takes non-negative values, it can be written as the sum of squares. (I think it may be helpful for the above problem, so I put the proof here)
Proof Let the polynomial be $\displaystyle C\prod\limits_{i=1}^n(x-x_i)$, where $n$ is even and $C\neq 0$. Consider an arbitrary root $x_j$ of this polynomial. There're two cases.
(i) $x_j$ is real. Then we claim the multiplicity $r_j$ of this root must be even. This is because if the multiplicity is odd, then we can consider the following function $\displaystyle f(x)=\frac{C\prod\limits_{i=1}^n(x-x_i)}{(x-x_j)^{r_j}}=C\prod\limits_{x_i\neq x_j}(x-x_i)$. Note that $x_i$ is not a root of $f(x)$, and therefore there exists a small enough $\varepsilon$ such that $\displaystyle f(x_j+\varepsilon)$ and $\displaystyle f(x_j-\varepsilon)$ have the same sign. However, since $\displaystyle C\prod\limits_{i=1}^n(x-x_i)$ always takes non-negative values and $(x-x_j)^{r_j}$ does not keep the same sign at $x=x_j-\varepsilon$ and $x=x_j+\varepsilon$ because $r_j$ is odd, we know that $\displaystyle \frac{C\prod\limits_{i=1}^n(x-x_i)}{(x-x_j)^{r_j}}$ does not keep the same sign at $x=x_j-\varepsilon$ and $x=x_j+\varepsilon$. This will lead to a contradiction.
(ii) $x_j$ is not real, say $x_j=a+bi$ where $b\neq 0$. Then we know that $a-bi$ is also a root. Then $(x-a-bi)(x-a+bi)=(x-a)^2+b^2$ divides $\displaystyle C\prod\limits_{i=1}^n(x-x_i)$.
From (i) and (ii), it's obvious that the polynomial can be written as a sum of squares.

there exists some research and softwares on SOS decomposition of quadratic forms. this seems like a nice exposition and reference to some tools. In general, degree four SOS decomposition is hard to figure out by hand, unless there is come cute trick available.

I doubt there is a sum of squares of polynomials.
But I have the following Sum of Squares:
\begin{align*}
 (16(a-b)^2 + 16(d-e)^2)\sum_{\mathrm{cyc}} (a-b)(a-c)(a-d)(a-e)
 &= 2f_1^2 + 2f_2^2 + 3f_3^2 + 3f_4^2
\end{align*}
where
\begin{align*}
 f_1 &= {a}^{3}-2\,{a}^{2}c-{a}^{2}e-3\,a{b}^{2}+3\,abc+2\,abd+abe+a{c}^{2}-ac
 e\\
 &\qquad -2\,ade+2\,a{e}^{2}+2\,{b}^{3}-{b}^{2}c-2\,{b}^{2}d-b{c}^{2}+bcd+b{d}
 ^{2}-bde\\
 &\qquad -{c}^{2}d+{c}^{2}e+2\,c{d}^{2}-3\,cde+c{e}^{2}-{d}^{3}+3\,d{e}
 ^{2}-2\,{e}^{3},\\
 f_2 &= 2\,{a}^{3}-3\,{a}^{2}b-{a}^{2}c-2\,{a}^{2}d+3\,abc+2\,abd+abe-a{c}^{2}
 +acd\\
 &\qquad +a{d}^{2}-ade+{b}^{3}-2\,{b}^{2}c-{b}^{2}e+b{c}^{2}-bce-2\,bde+2\,
 b{e}^{2}\\
 &\qquad -{c}^{2}d+{c}^{2}e+2\,c{d}^{2}-3\,cde+c{e}^{2}-{d}^{3}+3\,d{e}
 ^{2}-2\,{e}^{3},\\
 f_3 &= {a}^{3}-{a}^{2}b-{a}^{2}c-{a}^{2}e-a{b}^{2}+2\,abc+2\,abe-acd+ace+a{d}
 ^{2}\\
 &\qquad -ade+{b}^{3}-{b}^{2}c-{b}^{2}e-bcd+bce+b{d}^{2}-bde+2\,{c}^{2}d\\
 &\qquad -2
 \,{c}^{2}e-2\,cde+2\,c{e}^{2}-2\,{d}^{3}+4\,{d}^{2}e-2\,d{e}^{2},\\
 f_4 &= {a}^{3}-3\,{a}^{2}b+{a}^{2}c-{a}^{2}e+3\,a{b}^{2}-2\,a{c}^{2}+acd+ace-
 a{d}^{2}+ade\\
 &\qquad -{b}^{3}-{b}^{2}c+{b}^{2}e+2\,b{c}^{2}-bcd-bce+b{d}^{2}-bd
 e.
\end{align*}
(Note: If $(a-b)^2 + (d-e)^2 = 0$,
then $\sum_{\mathrm{cyc}} (a-b)(a-c)(a-d)(a-e) = 0$.)
Maple expressions for verifying (copy them into CAS-Computer Algebra Systems to verify the above identity):
2*f1^2+2*f2^2+3*f3^2+3*f4^2 = 2*(a^3-2*a^2*c-a^2*e-3*a*b^2+3*a*b*c+2*a*b*d+a*b*e+a*c^2-a*c*e-2*a*d*e+2*a*e^2+2*b^3-b^2*c-2*b^2*d-b*c^2+b*c*d+b*d^2-b*d*e-c^2*d+c^2*e+2*c*d^2-3*c*d*e+c*e^2-d^3+3*d*e^2-2*e^3)^2+2*(2*a^3-3*a^2*b-a^2*c-2*a^2*d+3*a*b*c+2*a*b*d+a*b*e-a*c^2+a*c*d+a*d^2-a*d*e+b^3-2*b^2*c-b^2*e+b*c^2-b*c*e-2*b*d*e+2*b*e^2-c^2*d+c^2*e+2*c*d^2-3*c*d*e+c*e^2-d^3+3*d*e^2-2*e^3)^2+3*(a^3-a^2*b-a^2*c-a^2*e-a*b^2+2*a*b*c+2*a*b*e-a*c*d+a*c*e+a*d^2-a*d*e+b^3-b^2*c-b^2*e-b*c*d+b*c*e+b*d^2-b*d*e+2*c^2*d-2*c^2*e-2*c*d*e+2*c*e^2-2*d^3+4*d^2*e-2*d*e^2)^2+3*(a^3-3*a^2*b+a^2*c-a^2*e+3*a*b^2-2*a*c^2+a*c*d+a*c*e-a*d^2+a*d*e-b^3-b^2*c+b^2*e+2*b*c^2-b*c*d-b*c*e+b*d^2-b*d*e)^2


How is this derived?? I mean how do you find this identity...

@grj040803 Use some solver for sum of squares. Before that use some transform $d - e = x_1, c - d = x_2, b - c = x_3, a - b = x_4$.
